How to prevent Auto Trigger of Azure Pipelines based on condition?
For a Business Central Extension, the key component is the app.json file which is unique to every extension. With each change in the extension, normally we would manually update the "version" from example 1.0.0.0 to 1.0.0.1.
But I need to be able to do this in a CICD Pipeline before Building the Extension and also commit the changes so that the next time the version is increased to 1.0.0.2. But the commit I make would trigger the next pipeline run as I have kept the trigger as main branch in the yaml file.
Is there any method to control the pipeline trigger? maybe not auto trigger if the changes are made by the previous pipeline?
or if the approach I am trying to take is wrong and there is a better approach, please do let me know. Thanks!
Have thought of using a custom commit message for example: --no-auto-trigger or something similar for the commit made by the pipeline and writing logic to stop the pipeline from running the next time. not tried it out!

Hi @SivaguruMuralidharan, Good day. Have you got a chance to check the answer by RUI below, which should help you skip unexpected trigger of pipeline runs? Thx for the time and efforts.


Have thought of using a custom commit message for example: --no-auto-trigger or something similar for the commit made by the pipeline and writing logic to stop the pipeline from running the next time.

You can tell Azure Pipelines to skip running a pipeline that a push would normally trigger. Just include [skip ci] in the message or description of any of the commits that are part of a push, and Azure Pipelines will skip running CI for this push. You can also use any of the following variations:

[skip ci] or [ci skip]
skip-checks: true or skip-checks:true
[skip azurepipelines] or [azurepipelines skip]
[skip azpipelines] or [azpipelines skip]
[skip azp] or [azp skip]
***NO_CI***

